# get notification if any akka actor died

Tags: scala, akka

does *Akka* have any mechanism to catch some message if **any** actor in context/system was crashed/disconnected etc?

for example: can I write some `WatchActor` which will to listen trigger like `Terminated`? But I dont wont to register each actor through `context.watch(aсtor)` or somthing like this.

Comment: Could it be that you *actually* mean "I don't want to inject the actorRef to my WatchActor into every actor in my entire code base"? That's a different problem. Notice that you can get a more-or less up-to-date view of all actors by using `ActorSelection` with `/*`-paths, and then sending `Identify` messages to every actor you encounter, and then collecting `ActorIdentity` responses and using them to `watch(sender)`. Would that be a compromise?

Comment: I was sure that in the Akka framework already implemented a mechanism for tracking the status of any actors in system and triggering of broadcast messages. and I just need to subscribe to them. then I'm wrong?

Comment: if new actor appear in system after this `ActorSelection` process then I need to rescan system? or in any case implement registration process in/for each actor...

Comment: Looks like it, yes. Otherwise, I could imagine that there might be some dispatcher implementations out there that support something like what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really anything built in, if you want to watch you need to do that explicitly.

If you are in control of all actors you could use a common supertype for all your actors that publishes some message to the event bus in `postStop`.

If it is for logging, you can enable actor lifecycle logging for all actors at debug level with `akka.actor.debug.lifecycle = on` in your configuration.

Comment: thx. as I understand `postStop` will not be called if actor just lost connection. or I'm wrong?

Comment: Post stop is always called when an actor stops (there is no such concept as lost connection there). In a remote actorsystem you will not see the messages published on the message bus, as that is a local abstraction. If you watch a remote actor and that actor system is downed that will lead to a Terminated message, if that is what you refer to.

Comment: thx. can you recommend some article where I can find the pattern of building an application with tracking the state of nodes (remote actors)? with Akka, of course.

Comment: This one could perhaps be interesting to look at: https://developer.lightbend.com/guides/akka-distributed-workers-scala/